# Android - Contract and Provider JOIN interaction

Tags: java, android, join, android-contentprovider

I just want to understand what's happening in my code in the Udacity Android course.

When I use a type of URI the JOIN statement works, but if I use another type of URI the JOIN does not work, and I can't understand why.

1-) When I JOIN it works:

```
String sortOrder = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATETEXT + " ASC";
    mLocation = settings.getLocation();
    Uri weatherForLocationUri = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocationWithDate(
            mLocation, DATE_KEY);
    Log.e("URI_REQUISITE", weatherForLocationUri.toString());

    return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity(),
            weatherForLocationUri,
            new String[] {
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_DESC,
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MAX_TEMP,
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MIN_TEMP,
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_HUMIDITY,
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WIND_SPEED,
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WEATHER_ID,
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_PRESSURE,
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DEGREES,
                WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTINGS // <- this row is the problem
                //^ this row is the problem
            },
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder
    );
```

2-) When I JOIN it does not work:

```
String sortOrder = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATETEXT + " ASC";
    return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity(),
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_DESC,
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MAX_TEMP,
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MIN_TEMP,
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_HUMIDITY,
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WIND_SPEED,
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WEATHER_ID,
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_PRESSURE,
                WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DEGREES,
                WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTINGS // <- this row is the problem
                //^ this row is the problem
            },
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATETEXT+" = ?",
            new String []{DATE_KEY},
            sortOrder
    );
```

You can see the `WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING` is not found in the second example and my application crashes!

Why in the first example is `WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING` found and in second example it's not?

For ease, this is my WeatherContract and my WeatherProvider:

[WeatherContract](https://github.com/bkawakami/Udacity-Sunshine/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sunshine/data/WeatherContract.java)

[WeatherProvider](https://github.com/bkawakami/Udacity-Sunshine/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sunshine/data/WeatherProvider.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objectively, this is the answer to my question.

SQLiteQueryBuilder -> setTables -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#setTables%28java.lang.String%29